# Help identifying a Megabloks set - grey and black mass

Tags: set-identification, 3rd-party

Could you help me work out what this set could be? Tried searching through Google Images, etc. and can’t find it.[image: Mega Bloks]

Comment: What you have asked for seems impossible to help with. The parts that can be identified in your photo are so generic they could be from almost any set. It would be like showing you a picture of a rounded grey stone and ask you to tell me what river it comes from.

Answer (score 5):

That is the fuselage of 9962 Supersonic Fighter:
[image]

However, it appears that the stickers haven’t been applied.